# Grafana Mimir: Configuration & data source

Tags: prometheus, grafana, snmp, grafana-mimir

I followed the guide given on the grafana mimir site https://grafana.com/tutorials/play-with-grafana-mimir/?pg=webinar-intro-to-grafana-mimir&plcmt=resources-list-2
I would like to understand if it is possible to configure the data sources that I am interested in, in order to use mimir on my machines used to monitoring several netwrok elements. In particular, I would like to understand if it is possible to configure mimir on a remote server instead of the localhsot mentioned in the guide (http://localhost:9000).

Thank you in advance for your help.